# Automatizar função de resposta do express (res.send())

Tags: node.js, api, http, express.js

Tenho uma api em express e gostaria de desenvolver uma função para padronizar a resposta para o cliente.

Código (executando a função):

```
response(200, "Evento adicionado com sucesso!", res)
```

Escopo da função:

```
function response(code, info, res) {

switch (code) {
    case 200:
        error = false
    case 201:
        error = false
    case 404:
        error = true
    case 401:
        error = true
    case 500:
        error = true
}
res.status(code)
return res.send({ error: error, info: info })

}
module.exports = {
    response: response
}
```

**O problema**

Não está dando a resposta para o cliente. Testei com `console.log()` no cliente e não exibe a resposta. A requisição é feita normalmente. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Não tem `break` nos seus `case`...

Comment: kkkkkkk, bah esqueci mesmo mano! É que tipo tem algumas funções do express que não pode usar break, daí não coloquei. Mas valeu !

Comment: E só preciso de duas atribuições, uma para `false` e outra para `true`, peesquise sobre o `case` e entenda com o se usa ele.